# Detected a Non-hex character at 1 or 2 position

Tags: spring-boot

> I am using spring boot 2.0.5 and used following code for password encoding.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder defaultEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

    DelegatingPasswordEncoder passworEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(
            "bcrypt", encoders);
    passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultEncoder);

    return passworEncoder;
}
```

> By the way,i generated encoded password using the above code from another project. Because in my current project i did not generate encoded password and i just copied that encoded password in my current projects database. The encoded password looks as below.

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$DPOPug/9As2jwQzW3Ezr1u3LE31kFaMR/z/8bMpQYHQUJ0b6NyZri
```

> The problem is when i use the password to login from the project where i generated the encoded string it works well. But when i use the same password to login from my current project it does not work. Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your method with the below method.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {

    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Reference : https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#constructing-delegatingpasswordencoder